# Beautifulsoup only scraping 8 results when there are more

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm teaching myself beautifulsoup and trying to scrape some reddit titles. The list, however, only contains 8 reddit titles. That's weird, since the page contains a lot more reddit titles (I tried saving it). What am I doing wrong and how can I get it to scrape the whole page?

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
page = requests.get("https://www.reddit.com/r/RedditWritesSeinfeld/search/?q=flair%3Aprompt&restrict_sr=1&sr_nsfw=&t=all&sort=top")
soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')
soupbody = soup.select("div h3") #Selects one element lists of all reddit titles
def listreddittitles(l): #returns a list of all reddit post titles as strings 
    temp = []
    for i in l:
        temp.append(i.contents[0])
    return temp
reddittitles = listreddittitles(soupbody)
print(len(reddittitles))
input()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is most probably loaded dynamically via JavaScript, so you need to simulate the Ajax with `requests` module.

Or

You can append `.json` to the URL and receive data from the server in Json format:

```py
import json
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0"
}

params = {
    "q": "flair:prompt",
    "restrict_sr": "1",
    "sr_nsfw": "",
    "t": "all",
    "sort": "top",
}

data = requests.get(
    "https://www.reddit.com/r/RedditWritesSeinfeld/search/.json",
    params=params,
    headers=headers,
).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for i, d in enumerate(data["data"]["children"], 1):
    print("{:<3} {}".format(i, d["data"]["title"][:50]))
```

Prints:

```
1   Jerry’s Australian girlfriend buys him a birthday 
2   George impresses his girlfriend with his generosit
3   George accidentally eats a pot brownie at a party.
4   George accidentally writes "Congrats! Way to Go!" 
5   What would George’s social media profiles look lik
6   In a very special episode, George, at his father F
7   Elaine starts dating a guy named George, so the re
8   There is a big protest in the city. George is inte
9   Jerry, horrified to find a mouse in his apartment,
10  George tries to find out what Doctor his Doctor se
11  George throws a tantrum on a date when they go to 
12  Jerry dates a marketing exec he met through Elaine
13  A true crime podcast accuses a notorious killer of
14  Kramer notices that a lot of runners are using the
15  “The George” - The name “George” becomes a viral t
16  Jerry dates a beautiful woman who has a quirk that
17  "She's a floor-sleeper!"
18  Jerry’s new girlfriend starts saying “y’all” even 
19  George developes an app that rates public restroom
20  Elaine's boyfriend's parrot says "Julia" over and 
21  The Gauntlet - George tries to wipe out half of al
22  George’s gf’s weighted blanket is too heavy for in
23  [Prompt] George saves a pregnant woman who is so g
24  Jerry's Italian girlfriend calls George "Giorgio;"
25  Frank might be deported to Italy due to an old pap
```

---

Or:

Use the url in the form of `"https://old.reddit.com/r/RedditWritesSeinfeld/search/` (note the **old.** at the beginning) and parse it with `beautifulsoup` library)

Comment: wow thank you you're a pro but can you explain the second option a lil more? I wanna learn a little bit of that expert level code.